# Sentry un-minifying code with source-map is not working

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4, sentry

i'm starting to use Sentry for monitoring my website.But in the issue detail, sentry cannot un-minify code with correct source file.

Following is my description to problem.

In the screenshot "IssueDetail",I got the file "/261710d8d/dist-helper/helper.umd.js" has error but cannot be um-minified.Because sentry can't find source in project release boundle.

In the screenshot "ProjectSourceMap", I searched file by the path copied from issue detail.Those files are right there.

So, in the issue stack frames i have right "abs_path".And in the specific project release, I have exactly those files right at abs_path.

Please some help, why sentry cannot un-minify the code.

[image: IssueDetail]
[image: ProjectSourceMap]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are two reasons for my problem:

1. The answer is, the project has been deleted before.And i the new one i created shares the same name -- "lcap-mdd-ide". Only change "dsn" in init options is not enough. So, when you create sentry projects, do not use same name.
2. I uploaded source file to same release for multiple times.For simply use, we upload source file to release base on commit for only once.But i have a second opinion, i upload source files with different urlPrefix to reuse the same release.

I think it's second one cause the problem.